# Incorrect payload in axiom post API formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks, formik

I am trying to create post request using formik in reactjs. but it is taking `value:` in `payload` thats why 400 error is coming.

```
const handleSubmit = async (values: any) => {
    await axios
        .post('http://localhost:3000/api/certificates', {
            values,
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('error in call');
            console.log(err);
        }); 
};
```

it is generating payload

```
{
  "values": {
    "sponser": "Hello",
    "startDate": "2021-11-22T13:50:59.073Z",
    "endDate": "2021-11-23T13:50:59.000Z",
    "phaseOfTrial": "1",
    "requestStatus": "DRAFT",
    "address": "Hello",
    "address2": "Hellpo",
    "zipCode": "12345",
    "city": "new",
    "protoColNo": "12312312",
    "molecules": "asdasda",
    "unAuthMolecule": "YES",
    "noOfSubjects": 5,
    "personInCharge": "llasdasdasda",
    "country": "asdasdasd",
    "comments": "asdasdasdasd",
    "attachedFile": "asdasdasd"
  }
}
```

in the `payload` it is taking `values:` in the beginning which my `API` not expecting. what mistake I am doing? how can I remove this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would work. There is shorthand assignment being done when you do like this `{values} => {values: values}`  Thank you

```
await axios
    .post('http://localhost:3000/api/certificates',values)
```

Comment: How to remove that?

Comment: If the above one doesn't works, try this one await axios
  .post('http://localhost:3000/api/certificates', 
 ...values)

Comment: @SrikanthMargam I suggest you to [edit] your answer to make a complete answer that explain everything clearly, to make Oze, the OP, well understand how he can fix it (and all other next reader).